# Como efetuar relacionamento no Seeds e Factories em AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, relacionamento, adonisjs, seeders

estou com a seguinte dúvida em relação aos Seeds e Factories.

Possuo o seguinte cenário: Quando o usuário é criado  automaticamente preciso que seja criado um registro de configurações na tabela UserConfig com o FK do usuário.

No controller eu crio desta forma:

```
class UserController {
  async store({ request }) {
    //Buscamos os campos do corpo da nossa requisição e os armazenamos em um objeto chamado data;
    const data = request.only([
      "name",
      "last_name",
      "date_birth",
      "cpf",
      "cep",
      "address",
      "uf",
      "city",
      "cellphone",
      "phone",
      "email",
      "password"
    ]);

    //Criamos um novo usuário repassando os parâmetros vindos da requisição e salvamos esse novo usuário em uma variável user;
    const user = await User.create(data);

    //Criando os dados de configuração do usuário
    await user.configuration().create({ user_id: user.id });

    //Retornamos o novo usuário como resultado da requisição, como selecionamos, no nosso caso o retorno será um JSON.
    return user;
  }
```

Neste caso eu faço uma busca nos usuários pelo email passado, pego o user, acesso sua id e crio o registro de configurações com esse user_id.

Porém como eu faço com que a seeder ocorra da mesma forma? 
Como eu consigo os dados do usuário após a criação do mesmo por meio da seeder?

Atualmente fiz algo desta forma:

Factory.js

```
/** @type {import('@adonisjs/framework/src/Hash')} */
const Hash = use("Hash");

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Factory')} */
const Factory = use("Factory");

Factory.blueprint("App/Models/Plan", async faker => {
  return {
    name: faker.name(),
    description: "testes",
    price: 20.99
  };
});

Factory.blueprint("App/Models/User", async faker => {
  return {
    plan_id: 1,
    name: faker.name(),
    email: faker.name() + "@gmail.com",
    password: await Hash.make(faker.password())
  };
});

Factory.blueprint("App/Models/Configuration", async faker => {
  return {
    user_id:  <-----Caso eu insira um valor fixo aqui é criado dois registros no banco um com o ID inserido e outro com ID original do usuario.
  };
});
```

Como faço para passar o valor do id do user criado?

Seeders

```
class ConfigurationSeeder {
  async run() {
    await Factory.model("App/Models/Configuration").create();
  }
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------

class UserSeeder {
  async run() {
    const user = await Factory.model("App/Models/User").create();
    console.log(user);
  }
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------

class PlanSeeder {
  async run() {
    await Factory.model("App/Models/Plan").create();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido da seguinte forma:

Removido da factory.js as Factories.blueprint de Configurações, e também removido os arquivos seeds de configurações e de planos.

Meu arquivo factory.js ficou da seguinte forma:

```
/** @type {import('@adonisjs/framework/src/Hash')} */
const Hash = use("Hash");

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Factory')} */
const Factory = use("Factory");

Factory.blueprint("App/Models/Plan", async faker => {
  var data = new Date();
  return {
    name: faker.name(),
    description: "testes",
    price: 20.99,
    expiration_date: data.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")
  };
});

Factory.blueprint("App/Models/User", async faker => {
  return {
    plan_id: 1,
    name: faker.name(),
    email: faker.name() + "@gmail.com",
    password: await Hash.make(faker.password())
  };
});
```

Após isso foi alterado a UserSeeder.js da seguinte forma:

```
/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Factory')} */
const Factory = use("Factory");

class UserSeeder {
  async run() {
    const plan = await Factory.model("App/Models/Plan").create();
    const user = await Factory.model("App/Models/User").make();
    await user.plan().associate(plan);
    await user.configuration().create({ user_id: user.id });
  }
}

module.exports = UserSeeder;
```

Feito isso, ao rodar  adonis seed usuário é criado juntamente com os registros de planos e configurações para cada usuário com seus determinados relacionamentos.

User sempre terá que ser vinculado a um único plano, ou seja um plano precisa existir antes de criar o user;
Um usuário após ser criado precisará ter relação com seu único registro de configurações pessoais na tabela de configurations;